# Groups and triangle-square complexes

Tags: gr.group-theory, complex-geometry, geometric-group-theory

I would like to know what kind of groups (and/or their group presentation) acting geometrically on CAT(0) curved piecewise Euclidean triangle-square complexes.

Thanks

Comment: You might be fishing for Stallings' theory of triangles of groups: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbifold#Triangles_of_groups

Comment: This is a very unfocused question. The class of such groups is huge. What specifically would you like to know?

Comment: Well, for starters, can't we always subdivide our squares into triangles?  So you could drop the 'square' hypothesis, I think.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. Specifically, I would like to know the group presentation of some (families of) hyperbolic groups which cayley graph is composed by triangles and squares. In other words, from the point of view of graph theory, all the simple cycles must have at most length 3 and 4 in such graph. For example, the cayley graph of triangle groups is composed by triangles. Additionally, by modified their group presentation the triangles can be ordinary Euclidean triangles, triangles on the sphere, or hyperbolic triangles.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_group

Comment: @MiguelC. It's now very unclear what you're asking.  Are you interested in hyperbolic groups?  CAT(0) groups? Triangle groups? If you're really interested in the groups from your other question, you should say so.  With Misha, I suggest you ask a more focussed question.